# fetch() sends lower case header keys

Tags: javascript

I'm writing an HTTP API library for use in Atom Electron. It is based on [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalFetch/fetch#Syntax). The server is outside of my control, but is written in PHP and I can see it checks headers in a case-sensitive fashion.

My code is something like:

```
const headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${key}`);

const init = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: headers 
} 

const req = new Request(baseUrl + '/items?format=json');
return fetch(req, init);
```

The request is rejected with a `403 FORBIDDEN` error. When I look at the request in the Electron Newtork panel, the request headers are present but `Authorization` has become `authorization`.

I know `fetch()` is just following the HTTP Standard, but is there a simple way to get `fetch()` to send the headers as I supply them?

Comment: @JaromandaX [The spec](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#terminology-headers) does say that all header names are _byte-lowercased_.

Comment: I originally stated that fetch does NOT do that - I can see now that it is ... the odd thing is, the way I tested was with PHP on nginx server ... and, in my case, PHP sees "Authorization" correctly - and indeed if I pass in "AuThOrIzAtIOn" ... php sees it as "Authorization" ... must be the HTTP server

Comment: @sdgluck - I removed that comment - see my comment above!

Comment: @sdgluck and the HTTP standard says they are case-insensitive so I don't think `fetch` is doing anything wrong as such

Comment: I have similar issue with a server expecting uppercase 'A' in Accept header, which i can't send correctly using fetch (using chrome 52 on mac).

Comment: https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/304 discussion of similar issue with some spec-incompliant server. Hope they will implement an option to pass headers as is without any normalization.

Comment: Please note that fetch() in Firefox and Chrome changes header case differently: Firefox normalizes some well-known headers to camel case and lowercases others, while Chrome lowercases everything

Comment: The standard seems to have addressed this in a Feb '17 commit -
 see https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/commit/5869c43a27fff06c6dfc228fe1288018f7f2168d. I'm not sure if this has made its way in to the library and I haven't tested to see if this fixes the issues above. Feedback would be welcome if anybody has!

Answer (score 9):

Currently fetch will `toLowercase()` all headers. (there is some discussion here https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/304 about optional disabling).

For now you may need to use http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ with the `header` option.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, that github issue was highlighted in one of the comments above so I've been checking in on it from time to time. I think in my case at least adding jQuery as a dependency for this task doesn't really make sense. I created an XMLHttpRequest directly as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox v110, Chromium v108:

Creating headers with constructor
`new Headers()` lowers the case, but providing request headers as plain object sends proper capital `Athorization: Bearer`

So instead of

```
fetch('api/end-point', {
  headers: new Headers(...)
})
```

I do this:

```
fetch('api/end-point', {
  headers: {
    ...{other headers},
    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
  }
})
```

Not tested in other environments

Answer (score -2):

Using fetch myself and doing a similar thing we do as follows...

```
const GLOBALS = require('./Globals');
const HEADERS = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
};
const resourceURL = '/some/endpoint'
const body = '';

var request = new Request(`${GLOBALS.API_ENDPOINT}${resourceURL}`, {
                        method: 'GET',
                        headers: new Headers(Object.assign(HEADERS, {'Authorization': `JWT ${token}`})),
                        body: body ? JSON.stringify(body) : null
                    }); 

return fetch(request)
    .then(res => consume)
```

Take is as pseudo pseudo code as there are some functional parameters we pass in that are evaluated in the template literal.

Comment: Does it help to get rid of an issue described in Q above?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, in my tests `fetch` still converts the headers to lowercase.

Comment: Answer doesn't resolve the question, since in some browsers `fetch` converts  header keys to lowercase — and that's the problem question is about.