# RTK Query setting REST headers to lowercase

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

Both in fetchBaseQuery and inside the single query definition when injecting endpoints RTK Query sets all my headers to lowercase, is there a way to keep the capitol letters inside the headers?

I know it's best to keep headers case insensitive, but I can't access the backend configurations since it's an external service.

code examples

```
const extendedApi = BaseApi.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (build) => ({
    getType: build.query<string[], string>({
      query: (param) => ({
        url: /test/${param}/call,
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Bearer token",
        }
      }),
    }),
  }),
  overrideExisting: false
});


export const BaseApi = createApi({
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL,
    prepareHeaders: (headers) => {
      headers.set('Authorization', "Bearer token")
      return headers
    }
  }),
  endpoints: () => ({}),
});
```

Comment: I'm a Redux maintainer. I'm looking at the source of `fetchBaseQuery` right now, and as far as I can see we _don't_ change any of the headers you provide. Based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34656412/fetch-sends-lower-case-header-keys , it looks like `fetch()` does that automatically.